# Git Bash not able to find the private key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am very new in Git and was trying to clone a remote repository in my local.

I have already created the ssh public private keys and registered my public key. 
My private key is in `C:\user\myuser\.ssh\id_rsa`.

I have one network drive which is tagged to my username as P: drive and I can see one .gitconfig file here in P: drive(not sure how it came here)

Now whenever I run the `git clone ssh://repository:9999/myproj.git` I get an error saying:

```
Cloning into myproj...
Could not create directory 'p/.ssh'
The authencity of host 'fullhost name with port' cant be established.
```

Can someone help me by saying what is the problem here? Is it something that Git is looking for private key in wrong location? If that is true then why it is trying to create .ssh directory there in P: drive?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question.  So if you're dead set on using SSH over HTTPS, then I would recommend following this [troubleshooting guide](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) on Github, which you indicate your using by the tags on this question.  It's helped me in the past, but I've since switched to HTTPS (validated by username/password) for all my projects.

If this alternate is acceptable, you can navigate to your repository on the [Github website](https://github.com/), then copy the URI which looks something something like `https://github.com/your-name/your-repository.git`.

Then just enter `git clone https://github.com/your-name/your-repository.git` into the command line on your local machine, enter your username & password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh or the Dir where git is install and check the ssh_config file. There is a property #   IdentityFile and by default looks for ~/.ssh/id_rsa. So you can either create a key with the default name or change the value of the property